# Getting the "disabled" version of an icon?

Tags: scripting, interface, properties

Is it possible to get the disable version of an icon? I mean, like when we set the `layout.enabled = False`?

(I need a property to look (only look) as disable, but being able to use it. But I would like it to have the disable look to inform the user that the changes are not taking into account.

Is it possible to get that greyed out version of a Blender icon?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you able to get the normal icon? Can you show a script that works for getting the normal icon? Then we can dig deeper to get the disabled version as well. What have you tried?

Comment: Hello there. I wasn't able to get the icon (and with the "icon" I guess I mean their ImagePreview). I think getting their ImagePreview may be the key, since with it we would ble to modify the original icon and kinda create a new image from them (like modifying their original alpha, or anything else) and then add those modified versions to an image preview.

But I'm not sure if we are able to get their image preview from their name/icon_id.

Answer (score 0):

Not answering to your question directly, maybe there's a way to somehow disable the icon but not the widget it is from.

But if I am not wrong, Blender usually uses a couple of icons for these cases. And maybe you or future readers could use them.

If you use the Icon Viewer addon shipped with Blender, you can see lots of icons are actually two : one for the active and one for the inactive state.

A few examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In which case, it can be as simple as creating a boolproperty, let the button set its icon from it, and toggle the bool property when clicked.

Example:

```py
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel

bpy.types.Scene.my_toggle_property = bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False)

class TEXT_PT_test(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Text"
    bl_label = "Test"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene

        hide_icon = "HIDE_OFF" if scene.my_toggle_property else "HIDE_ON"
        layout.prop(scene, "my_toggle_property", icon=hide_icon, text="")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(TEXT_PT_test)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEXT_PT_test)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]